# Performant and thread-safe initialization block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

I just stumbled over the following piece of code and I'm wondering if there is a prettier alternative which has the same performance.

```
if (!isInitialized) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            // Initialization code
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }           
}
```

For sure, the outer if statement could be removed with no impact regarding thread safety. But it would have an impact to performance when multiple threads would call the code at the same time since the isInitialized check could only be done in one thread at once.

Doing the initialization in a static context is no option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This double-check-idiom (DCI or DCL for double check locking) is known for it's flaw because of instruction reordering.

It only works if you declare the `isInitialized` variable as volatile, and only with jdk1.5+ (when volatile semantics and memory model got fixed).

Honestly, it's not that common anymore, with so much bad press...LOL.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the term double-check-idiom (DCL). That helped me to google it and to find more information. As I found out, there is no prettier alternative to the DCL.